# SQL Server logins for ASP.NET CMS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

We have completed developing a custom CMS using ASP.NET. The CMS will be setup in IIS hundreds to thousands of times (one per domain). The CMS uses SQL Server to store page content, settings etc.

Should we create a new SQL Server login (using SQL Authentication) for every website or should we use the same login for all websites?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated

Comment: Are there separate databases for each instance?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned this, yes every website (cms instance) has its own database (same SQL Server instance)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to the trouble of provisioning a separate CMS and DB for each instance, then you should create a separate sql login for each instance.

This way you add one more layer of security to the design (and incur little more of your already hellish maintenance cost).

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, we developed a CMS a few years ago and had a login for each install, this has worked fine. I was thinking it maybe be better performance to use a shared login. Regarding maintenance, this is a fully automated process so no real concern with that.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem safer to let each site have it's own login.

That way you can't look at the wrong content database by accident (or mischief).

I would advise using Windows Authentication in SQL. It is easier to set up, and doesn't require storing passwords in web.config files.

You can further restrict this user account for security purposes.

Also don't let these user accounts use the same passwords, that screams insecurity.

Comment: thanks, interesting idea regarding using windows authentication, we have in the past used a different SQL login and password per site. Is there an API to setup the windows account per site? (we currently do this during setup using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.

Comment: @user1843086: i'm sure there is tooling available for automation of user accounts and permissions. I would advise using `PowerShell` or a combination of `MSBuild` and the excellent `MSBuild Extension Pack`. You can use the extension pack for setting up IIS (sites, app pools, applciations) as well.